# Accessing an application using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser, twill

I am planning to access a https application(via browser) for form submission and other operations and I would like to carry this out using Python.

(Like accessing an application for timesheet submission, procuring data etc)

Is twill/webbrowser a better option or are there other modules which can be used?

Comment: Although Twill is good, I would suggest using selenium with Chromedriver or Firefoxdriver. Here's something to get you started 
https://bangladroid.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/how-to-install-python-pip-selenium-chrome-driver/

Comment: The one you have suggested does not deal with python ? Is this supported in all the browsers ?  As I have no idea about Selenium I would like to know if there are other packages for python to go ahead with...

Comment: The link mentioned above is for setting up python and supports Chrome and Firefox. Since your question mentions "Is twill/webbrowser a better option or are there other modules which can be used?" I suggested selenium because of the support provided by the python community.

Comment: ok cool..thank you NIkhil

Comment: @NikhilFadnis:  Should I download a separate driver for IE?